# Spring Data organization in layered multi-project application

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data

I know the basic Spring Boot organisation with :
Application

- Repository
- Controller
- Model
- Services

My problem is that I have to implement a database in a layered application:

- presentation : package /presentation
- application : package /application
- domain : package /domain
- infrastructure : package /infrastructure

@SpringBootApplication tag is under /presentation
@Entity is under /infrastructure

So that does not respect basic SpringBootApplication Structure
As I start the application, the database is not created.
How to do it correctly?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put the application class in parent package (so under java folder)

Comment: I can’t. Architecte obligation

Answer (score 0):

The application layer manages the flow of applications, so you should locate it in the application module.